# Java Eclipse saying my version of JVM is not suitable

Tags: java, eclipse

I run the windows 10 64 bit version of Eclipse. The first time I log onto Eclipse it works just fine (though I haven't fun any code yet, so I'm not sure if that works) but upon closing and reopening Eclipse it says, "Version 1.8.0_301 of the JVM is not suitable for this product: version 11 or greater is required." and immediately quits. I have downloaded jdk 16 and installed it. Redownloading Eclipse fixes it until I close it again. How can I fix this? I am a new Java programmer and am not experienced with any of this.

Comment: You may want to start eclipse with java 16, not just install that

Comment: One option is to force Eclipse to use a particular VM, by adding two lines in the eclipse.ini file above -vmargs: `-vm` and a line like `C:/Program Files/AdoptOpenJDK/jdk-11.0.6.10-hotspot/bin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a folder like ths: `C:\Program Files\Java`. In there, there should be a folder named 1.8.0_301. Delete this folder and reinstall java.
I had the same problem, this solved it for me...

Comment: This Worked! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could mark my answer as solution, so others with the same problem know what to do?

Comment: I tried this. Did not work for me. Message still says, "Version 1.8.0_321 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 11 or greater is required".

Comment: @lurker were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: I didn't delete mine, but prefixed it with "old_". So it's now `C:\Program Files\Java\old_jre1.8.0_331`.

I didn't delete it since my Eclipse Oxygen.3 March 2018 maybe uses it. I just recently came into a realization that I may be using a very old version of Java, installed by my mentors 5+ years ago.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, But I have deleted only JRE folder inside java folder

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you check the version of your eclispe IDE. You may have downloaded a version that doesn't supprot your installed jdk.

This link should provide you with the suitable jdk version for every eclipse version.
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation.

I hope I helped you a bit.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Java version 1.8.0_351.
In the program management settings of Windows I removed Java 8. After that, my Eclipse installation worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

There will be an eclipse.ini file where it is mentioned which Jdk it is pointing at and the minimum required version. Try tweaking it according to your requirements and it should solve the problem.